# Data migration between postgresql-9 and postgresql-11

Tags: linux, postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-cluster

What is the best way to migrate postgres-9 database with size of hundreds GB to postgres-11 ? I'm afraid that third party tools will take too long to do this.

Comment: You should consider upgrading to PostgreSQL version 16. Version 11 is already out of support. The least supported is 12, but its support will end soon too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [postgres 9 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/migration.html):

> For major releases of PostgreSQL, the internal data storage format is
> subject to change, thus complicating upgrades. The traditional method
> for moving data to a new major version is to dump and reload the
> database

The above is the recommended approach. Otherwise, you can try an in-place upgrade via `pg_upgrade`:

> The contrib program pg_upgrade allows an installation to be migrated
> in-place from one major PostgreSQL version to the next

However, upgrading *two* major releases can possibly ask too much from `pg_upgrade`.

Before doing anything, **be sure to have a confirmed-good backup** (I suggest *both* a logical dump and a physical datadir copy taken with the database stopped).

Finally, both postgres 9 and 11 are very old. *Upgrade to a newer (and supported) version as soon as possible.*